# Hibernate @ManyToMany deletes / re-adds all relationships when just one is modified

Tags: hibernate

I noticed that Hibernate is behaving less-than-optimal with ManyToMany relationships... This is causing issues because my relationship table also has last-updated timestamps (maintained automatically by MySQL), but Hibernate is deleting/inserting too much, screwing with my timestamps.

My setup:

- A many-to-many relationship between A and B
- The database contains A(id=1) relating to 10 B's(ids from 1 to 10)

When I remove one relationship between A(id=1) and say B(id=10), Hibernate does the following:

- Delete all relationships between A(id=1) and B
- Insert relationships from A(id=1) to B(ids from 1 to 9)

What I'd like to happen instead is:

- Just delete relationship between A(id=1) and B(id=10)

Can this be done with Hibernate??

Here are the entities:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="a_b_ref")
    private List<B> b;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="b")
    private List<A> a;
    ...
}
```

And the test code:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Test
@Transactional
public void test1() {
    A a = new A();
    a.setB(new ArrayList<B>());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        B b = new B();
        em.persist(b);
        a.getB().add(b);
    }
    em.persist(a);
    em.flush();
    a.getB().remove(9);
    em.flush();
}
```

The last flush issues this SQL:

```
delete from a_b_ref where a_id=?
insert into a_b_ref (a_id, b_id) values (?, ?)
insert into a_b_ref (a_id, b_id) values (?, ?)
insert into a_b_ref (a_id, b_id) values (?, ?)
insert into a_b_ref (a_id, b_id) values (?, ?)
insert into a_b_ref (a_id, b_id) values (?, ?)
insert into a_b_ref (a_id, b_id) values (?, ?)
insert into a_b_ref (a_id, b_id) values (?, ?)
insert into a_b_ref (a_id, b_id) values (?, ?)
insert into a_b_ref (a_id, b_id) values (?, ?)
```

Whereas what I want is:

```
delete from a_b_ref where a_id=? and b_id=?
```

Comment: Please post the full entity mapping (uni-directional or bi-directional many-to-many, cascade type, eager or lazy loading, ...) and relevant code parts (do you set a reference to a new collection or remove from the persistent collection, do you load, remove and save in the same session or in different ones, ...).

Comment: Bi-directional m2m, lazy loading. Attached more details.